# Не подключается JS-скрипт:

Tags: javascript, html5

```html
<div class="block__content">
                <script src="https://ra.revolvermaps.com/0/0/6.js?i=02op3nb0crr&amp;m=7&amp;s=320&amp;c=e63100&amp;cr1=ffffff&amp;f=arial&amp;l=0&amp;bv=90&amp;lx=-420&amp;ly=420&amp;hi=20&amp;he=7&amp;hc=a8ddff&amp;rs=80" async="async"></script>
              </div>
```

Я пробовал менять https на http и совсем убирать эти протоколы, также копировал код с сайта и вставлял в отдельный js-файл. В консоле возникает следующие ошибки[image: Ошибки]

Comment: Где подключаете? Что за проект?

Comment: @InDevX, по ошибке ж видно.

Comment: @Qwertiy такое бывает и на фреймворках, по ошибке вижу только ошибку (warning этот, по сути, всё говорит)

Comment: @InDevX, по красным ошибкам - `file://ra.revolvermaps.com/...` - если он сам не писал `file:`, то это тот случай, когда он убрал протокол и хром `//` раскрывает тоже в `file://`.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо! не знал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открой свою страницу не как файл, а как сайт. Например, установи nodejs, затем

```
npm i -g http-server
```

а потом в папке со своей html-страницей

```
http-server -c-1 -p 8082
```

и открывай http://localhost:8082